# Confusion about the coefficient of surface tension and the relation between force and length of a body

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics

[image: U shaped tube]

I haven't found a software that can create 3d or 2d shapes filled with liquids so I posted this picture. I know that the p=2σ/r where p is the pressure that goes inside the liquid and I guess that σ is the coefficient of the surface tension? I'm asking this because the formula σ=F*l gives me a lot of confusion. F meaning the mechanical force that acts over the length of a surface? Like,for example,if the water flows from the first cylinder to the second one that happens because of the force F=W(weight)?
2σ represents the Force that acts inside a tube like the one in my picture? If the value would be 4σ what would that mean? The force that acts inside the tube has a 4 times length(4l)?
Also I found another formula that gives me a hard time: W=σΔS where W here is mechanical work measured in joules. If ΔS means the difference between two three dimensional surfaces that means that we have to calculate the volume of each object? For example, if we have 1 spherical drop of mercury that is poured inside a recipient and after a short time by pouring another drop of mercury(the surface being spherical) that means that both of the surfaces use the formula for the spheres 4πr^3/3 and 4πR^3/3 for each drop and you subtract them?
[image: some formulas]
In the second image I showed you the formulas that were giving me a headache. N in the second picture represents the ratio of the masses(M means the mass of 30 to 50 liquid substances drops and m is the mass of a liquid substance drop).
I don't really understand all these informations so I really need help from someone to correct me.
There is also something else which I found and not understand. p=p0+(4σ/R) or p=p0+(2σ/R) where R is radius. So what does 2σ/R and 4σ/R mean when they are equal to the pressure(p)?

Comment: I'm sorry for the way I wrote this topic but I couldn't find examples of 3d shapes in google and examples of how the drops of substances(water,mercury) have the shape of a sphere..

Comment: Imagine surface tension to act the same as a membrane drawn over the surface of the fluid at its interface with the gas.  If the surface is curved, then, for the "membrane" to be in equilibrium, the fluid and gas pressures on the two sides of the membrane must differ (like with a balloon under tension).  The surface tension is the force per unit length within the surface of the membrane.  This pulls equally in all directions within the surface.

Comment: @ChetMiller And what about the surface energy? How do you understand it from the formulas in the second image?

Comment: @ChetMiller I have found an article about the surface energy but I don't understand a lot from it(https://byjus.com/physics/surface-energy/)

Comment: I hope that I get more answers because the answer from @ChetMiller is not helping me a lot and I would like an answer that is long and detailed!

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with your questions about surface energy.  I have been more interested in the practical applications of the surface tension concept for solving fluid mechanics problems.

Comment: Can someone else help me?

Comment: The change in surface energy is, according to my previous description, equal to the surface tension times the change in surface area.